# Traveling outside the country with a changed last name and un-updated passport and green card

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, passports, us-permanent-residents

I recently changed part of my last name several months ago after marriage, but I have not yet updated my passport and green card to reflect this change. On the other hand, I updated my SSN and driver's license. I am planning to get a Schengen visa and travel there soon. I am wondering if there are any potential issues that I should be aware of for visa application (interview) or when returning back to the US.

Has anyone had a similar experience? Should I take any specific steps to avoid any potential issues? I would greatly appreciate any advice or insights that you may have.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found a similar question, but it's from 6 years ago. I'm not sure if it's still valid.

Comment: I do not think anything has changed in the last 6 years in this respect. Can you please provide the link to the older question?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85498/applying-for-schengen-uk-tourist-visa-changed-name-after-marriage-but-maiden?rq=1